# MVC 4 and jQuery getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

I have to implement some sort of live search in a project at the university. I have the following code:
MVC Action:

```
[Authorize]  
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]  
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public JsonResult Search(string term)  
{  
    var data = ... // get matching item  
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Script in View:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#searchText").keyup(function() {  
        $.getJSON('/Search/Search', { "term": $(this).val() },  function(result) {   
            alert(result);    
            $("#searchText").val(result.d);  
        });  
    });  
});
```

The controller action is called and returns the matching objects, but the javascript function is never  called, no alert box, nothing. What can  do to make this work?

Comment: Check the console for errors as there is nothing specifically wrong with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a problem with the JSON serialization of your data. This could often happen if you are attempting to directly serialize your EF domain models which might contain circular references, ... The correct approach is of course to use view models.

In order to track the problem use [`FireBug`](http://getfirebug.com/) and look at the `Network` tab to see the exact request/response of the AJAX call. There you will be able to see the response returned by the server which will contain the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the serialization was the problem. Using FireBug was the  key.