# How to convert LINQ result to JSON and pass it to View in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller i have the following code

```
public ActionResult 
{
    var roomdetails = db.RoomDetails.Include(r => r.RoomType).Include(r => r.FloorNames);

    roomdetails = roomdetails.OrderByDescending(s => s.FloorNames.FloorName);

    return View(roomdetails.ToList());
}
```

But i want to send the roomdetails as json object so that i can use jquery to catch the request and do further dynamic processing in my View.So how to convert roomdetails to json object.Please help me...

Comment: Have you looked at JSON.NET?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Use Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 8.0.2

return an instance of this class to your controller method.

```
public class ActionResult_Json : System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
{
    public object To_Serialize_Object { get; set; }
    public ActionResult_Json(object To_Serialize_Object)
    {
        this.To_Serialize_Object = To_Serialize_Object;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        //serialize object to string
        string Serialized_Object_String =          Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(To_Serialize_Object, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        });
        //write json to response stream
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(Serialized_Object_String);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var roomdetails = db.RoomDetails.Include(r => r.RoomType).Include(r => r.FloorNames)
                                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.FloorNames.FloorName);
    return Json(roomdetails.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

You would need your jquery to process the json in the way that you want and display what you want. Typically this works well if it's called from your view via ajax.

Comment: But i get the error mesage'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: The above should work. If it does not, take a look at Darin's answer here (use view models instead of passing down your EF domain model): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548170/mvc-4-and-jquery-getjson

Answer (score -1):

@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
```

}

### Reception

$(document).ready(function () {











        $.getJSON('/Reception/Index1', function (data) {

           
            console.log(data);

            if (data.success) {

                alert("hai");

                //ShowStockQuote(data);

            }

            else {

                alert("faliure");

            }

        });

    });

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

Answer (score -2):

You may try this.

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var roomdetails = db.RoomDetails.Include(r => r.RoomType).Include(r => r.FloorNames);
    roomdetails = roomdetails.OrderByDescending(s => s.FloorNames.FloorName);

    return Json(roomdetails.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: when it put this code it shows no error message                            public JsonResult Index1()
        {
            var roomdetails = db.RoomDetails.Include(r => r.RoomType).Include(r => r.FloorNames)
                                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.FloorNames.FloorName);
            return Json(roomdetails.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }                                                                             but i dont know how to get the vlues in jquery

Comment: I made a correction to add the Method name and the return type (should be Json, not View).  Hmm, is it an error in where you're pulling back your data?

Comment: i am tyring to pull the data using the following code     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('/Reception/Index1', function (data) {
            alert("hai");
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) {

                //ShowStockQuote(data);
            }
            else {
                alert("faliure");
            }
        });
    });
</script>   but no result

Comment: Does it even make it to the method at the moment?

Comment: yes the control comes to this method and returns back, but in the view  when i try to diaplay atleast an alert the code is not working.so i am not sure whats happening in my jquery...

Comment: Weird...  I've done the same thing in the past and I always got to my alert even before data manipulation.  Can you post more of your view?